# How to deny crontab to group

Tags: linux, centos, cron, group

I'm trying to deny crontab to group but I had no success so far.

Nor I saw how to do it, or even discussions about it.

Is it possible to deny crontab to groups instead of users?

Imagine if you have 10 users, and want to deny access to 7.
As far as I can tell, there is only two options. deny 7 or allow 3.
the same applies if you have 100 000 users and want to deny 70 000. either you deny 70 000 or allow 30 000.

this is not practical at all and I believe that should be some kind of workaround.

Comment: this is a workaround on Debian https://superuser.com/q/1078301/370509, but as mentioned it's only Debian specific to have such ability, but I think there should  be a way that it's out of my knowledge to know that or answer. maybe some wizard here can answer.

Comment: It's a common configuration that only users in the `crontab` group are allowed to use cron.  In such a configuration, the 3 users you want to have access would be members of that group, and the other 10 would not be members of that group.  Does your configuration not support this approach?  In general, group membership _enables_ you do do things; it doesn't _prevent_ you from doing things.

Comment: Can you simply turn your group into a list of users for the `/etc/cron.d/cron.deny` file? Example: `line=$(getent group grouptodeny); echo ${line##*:} | sed 's/,/\n/g' > /etc/cront.d/cron.deny`

Comment: Hi @AndyDalton, In my configuration that approach doesnt work cause the deny/allow cron files doesnt recognize groups

Comment: Hi @JeffH., thank you for your workaround, I've tested and it correctly gives what I expect. But isn't there an official way of doing this using groups directly?